# How to solve this problem through bisection search or any other method?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have an optimization problem in the form

$$\text{Minimize}\hspace{1mm}D$$

$$\text{subject to}$$

$$\sigma_1+\sigma_2=\sigma$$

$$\rho_1+\rho_2=\rho$$

$$\epsilon\le\rho_i\le c_i\hspace{1mm},i=1,2$$

$$\sigma_i\ge 0\hspace{1mm},i=1,2$$

$$(c_i-\rho_i)D\ge \sigma_i+f_i(c_i-\rho_i)$$

I think a feasible solution can be found by bisection search.

Here $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$, $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are optimization variables.

For given values of $\sigma$, $\rho$, $c_1$, $c_2$, $f_1$, $f_2$ and $\epsilon$, How Can we solve this problem?

For example, $\sigma=25$, $\rho=10$, $f_1=4$, $f_2=5$, $c_1=2.5$, $c_2=3$ and $\epsilon=0.0001$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fix your $D$, your problem become a linear programming problem.

Hence one possible approach is to start with a value of $D$, and solve the corresponding LP.

If it is feasible, try a smaller value of $D$. If it is not feasible, try a bigger value of $D$.

We can first try $D=0$. If it is not feasible, we know the minimal $D$ is positive.If it is feasible, the minimal $D$ is nonpositive.

If $D>0$, you can try steps of the form of $2^{i}$, $i=1,2,3,\ldots$ until it is feasible. Then zoom down to fidn the best $D$.

If $D \leq 0$, reduce $D$ until it become infeasible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Frankly speaking, I am not an OR guy. Can you be a bit more detailed. Is it a kind of heuristic approach? If I fix $D$, what will be the LP form? Would you please elaborate your answer. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: When you fix $D$, let say $D=0$, the last constraint become $0 \geq \sigma_i + f_i (c_i-\rho_i)$ which is linear. You can set the objective function to be zero, and our problem become a sequence of feasibility test. However, I realized that we have to handle some special cases. In particular, when $c_i=\rho_i$, $D$ is unbounded.

Comment: thanks for your answer. In fact, this formulation is a tiny part of my original problem. The special cases you mentioned are handled by other tiny problems. For this case $c_1\neq \rho_i, ,i=1,2$
 How to write the objective function when I fix the value of $D$
? I mean $\text{Minimise} \cdots$?

Comment: minimize 0, it is just a feasibility problem

Comment: you mean whatever value I fix for $D$, the objective should be always minimize 0? For example, starting with $D=0$, the objective is minimise 0. Lets say $D=0$ is feasible, then we fix $D$ to a lower value. For example,  If we fix $D=-2$, still the objective is minimise 0?

Comment: that was my initial thought. We just want to find out if it is feasible. Another remark: your question looks like minimax of fractional programming to me.